# Update table query with multiple values to a column

Tags: sql-server-2014

Table name: sales

```
Country salesAmount ID
USA     2345         1
USA     4356         2
USA     8762         3
USA     7809         4
USA     54324        5
UK      56790        6
UK      234145      NULL  --> add 7
UK      567790      NULL  --> add 8
UK      345678      NULL  --> add 9
UK      343456      NULL  --> add 10
UK      5467891     NULL  --> add 11
UK      5923765     NULL  --> add 12
Japan   43567890    NULL  --> add 13
China   34566878    NULL  --> add 14
France  343466      NULL  --> add 15
Austria 3556689     NULL  --> add 16
India   34567891    NULL  --> add 17
Italy   3456767     NULL  --> add 18
```

I need to fill in the null values with the numbers next to the arrows. Is there a quicker way to add those numbers into the ID column instead of using the code          (Update sales set ID=7 where salesAmount = 234145)

I have to use the update statement for each row until the end which is time-consuming. Is there a stored procedure or function that I could use to update all the rows in one query? Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can with `ROW_NUMBER()`.

```
UPDATE A SET ID = New_ID FROM (
SELECT 
    ID, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, ID) AS New_ID 
    -- The row numbers are ordered by whether ID is null first, then by ID so that the nulls are at the end of the order
    FROM sales
) AS A
WHERE ID IS NULL
```